# How to change postgresql.conf default values on Openshift

Tags: git, postgresql, cakephp, openshift

I've been running a CakePHP installation on OpenShift for six months. The database is PostgreSQL 9.2, i used to setup the `postgresql.conf` file via shell, editing `postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` (there is another postgresql.conf file in `postgresql/conf/postgresql.conf` that didn't keep the changes after db restarts), after setting up the file for the first time everything was ok until today that i git pushed some changes, restarted the application hence the database, and the application was showing me errors related with database datestyle, verifiyng that the `postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`file was reset, i tried to change the default configuration but after restarting the application it was overwrited by openshift to its defaults.

I'm using this git repository for the set up https://github.com/BanzaiMan/openshift-cakephp-example-postgresql

Did Openshift changed the way to configure `postgresql.conf`?
Is there any other way to change `postgresql.conf` default values?

I need to change

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Locale and Formatting -

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'  
lc_messages = 'en_US.utf8'  
lc_monetary = 'en_US.utf8'  
lc_numeric = 'en_US.utf8'  
lc_time = 'en_US.utf8'  
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

to this

```
datestyle = 'iso, dmy'  
lc_messages = 'es_BO.utf8'  
lc_monetary = 'es_BO.utf8'  
lc_numeric = 'es_BO.utf8'  
lc_time = 'es_BO.utf8'  
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

**UPDATE**

The issue has been reported: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1123587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not edit the data/postresql.conf directly as this configuration is regenerated after application start/restart.

I added `OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_LOCALE` environment variable you can use to change the default locale. It should be available in the next release of Online.

https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/pull/5664

Thanks for reporting this! If you need more configuration tweaking, please open an bug :-)

Comment: Can i ask when is it going to be the next release of Online?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the values can be changed as mentioned in the following article https://www.openshift.com/blogs/more-online-features-for-april-2014. Here's how I changed the max number of connections.

```
SHOW max_connections;
max_connections 
-----------------
100
(1 row)
```

Then set the environment variable:

```
rhc env-set OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_MAX_CONNECTIONS=200 -a ruby
Setting environment variable(s) ... done
```

Restart the application

```
rhc app restart ruby
```

Then re-check the parameters:

```
 SHOW max_connections;
 max_connections 
 -----------------
 200
 (1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any modifications you want to a ConfigMap and then mount it to /opt/app-root/src/postgresql-cfg/yourModifications.conf

All the *.conf files from that folder will be included at the bottom of the generated postgresql.conf on runtime.

Source: https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container/tree/master/examples/custom-config

I have tested it on OpenShift 3.9 and 3.11.