# postgreSQL in OpenShift remote access

Tags: postgresql, openshift

I have PostgreSQL pod in OpenShift and I want to make some integration tests in my java application directly from IDE.

I tried to create route to service, but i can't connect to route hostname and 5432 port

I also tried to create LoadBalancer service. It has ClusterIP and External IP, but i can't even ping external IP.

The only working solution I found is oc port-forward.

But is there any other way to make my PostgreSQL pod accesed remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured out how to connect to postgre remotely.

First of all I used 3rd answer about config maps to set listen_adresses to '*' in postgresql.conf
[How to change postgresql.conf default values on Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955590/how-to-change-postgresql-conf-default-values-on-openshift)

Then, after creating pod with correct .conf i created loadBalance service as it said in 2nd answer 
[Can PostgreSQL service in OpenShift cluster receive external traffic via exposed route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405186/can-postgresql-service-in-openshift-cluster-receive-external-traffic-via-exposed?rq=1)

After that I figured out what port was assigned with the "oc export service SERVICE_NAME" command. In the output of this command the port will be in the "-nodePort: " section.

To connect postgre we need to use node-ip:node-port
node-ip is shown in pod-info in openshift web console